Unable to add Firebase dependency in android for react native application React-Native V 0.74.2
I created a Project to test FCM Push notification for which i created a project from Firebase console and registered android application by putting the package name from react native android project. But when I am going to next step it is showing me to add firebase sdk, for this i need to add inside
project level build.gradle:
plugins {
  // ...

  // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
  id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.2' apply false

}

and inside app level build.gradle
plugins {
  id 'com.android.application'

  // Add the Google services Gradle plugin
  id 'com.google.gms.google-services'

  ...
}

but there is no plugins block
plugins {
  ...
}

available in both build.gradle files and the project is unable to sync if i added directly like
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"

just below
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"

I think there is some change in the way plugin should be added in the build.gradle files.
Can anyone have idea where to find the solution for this issue, or where i can refer to the latest way to add a plugin.

What do you mean by "no plugins block in both build.gradle file"?

what i mean by no plugins block available is plugins {....} is not there in the file where i can add the plugins required for firebase. Instead of plugins {...} there is
apply plugin: apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"

Yes, but the plugins {} block should be there. I am not sure how you created the project. Have you tried creating it from Android Studio instead?

I have created the project using npx @react-native-community/cli@latest init ProjectName command. I think there is some other way of adding plugins apart from the plugins block, there is some legacy way of adding plugins for which there is a link but it does not specify how to use it correctly. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:script_plugins

This looks so outdated, on Android we are using version catalogs already. Sorry not familiar with RN.

I found solution through this link
https://rnfirebase.io/#configure-firebase-with-android-credentials
You need to add classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8' in build.gradle project level inside buildscript dependencies block
buildscript {
    ....
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        .....
    }
}

and
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' 

in the same build.gradle file
